# Mongoose - Check if each key of .findOne() doc is a ObjectId (referenced object)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I got a generic GET function that worps for my entire app, considering I am using just absolute documents.

Now I get to a point that I need some properties of some of my documents reference others, and when executed, the GET function populate them (obviously). For that, I need to require the referenced schema, and populate with referenced model.

The point is: I want to my GET function stay generic, so I don't want to reference any of my schemas, unless it is needed. The same goes for the .populate() method.

To achieve that, I am iterating through each key of the resulting object of the .findOne() method, and trying to check if each specific key, is or is not a ObjectId/reference or not. something like this:

```
require('../schemas/mySchema').findOne({'slug': req.params.slug}, function(err, doc){
            console.log(mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(doc[key]));
        });
```

But the only true value it returns is for the "id"and "__v" properties (no idea where these came from... I did not set them. _id is also false), all the rest comes as false (including a given property that IS a reference, tested and working)

Is there any way to do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I believe mongoose returns references with the objectId nested - in the same structure as a populated object but having only the _id key. Try this:

```
var item = doc[key];
if (typeof item === 'object') {
  console.log(mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(item._id));
}
```

Comment: still false result =(